# Text wrapping in WPF hyperlink

Tags: wpf, xaml, hyperlink, word-wrap

In my WPF application I have this:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock>
     <Hyperlink>
       <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="HyperlinkText" />
     </Hyperlink>
  </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

But if I set `HyperlinkText.Text` to a long text that wraps, the whole text is underlined only once at the bottom (see image). Is there a way to have every line underlined separately without manual wrapping?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easier way to achieve that is to use `Run` instead of TextBlock.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that works too and is much simpler. (I had to move the TextWrapping="Wrap" from the inner TextBlock to the outer one.)

Comment: Why does this link take me to a security check?

Answer (score 17):

This is a really, really annoying problem in WPF. I'd go so far as to call it a bug.

As @levanovd mentioned in his answer, you can get a hyperlink to wrap properly by using a `Run` as the inner element:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Hyperlink><Run>This is a really long hyperlink. Yeah, a really really long hyperlink, whaddaya think?</Run></Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

This works great, until you want to apply text formatting *within* the hyperlink. If you tried to do this, for example:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Hyperlink><Run>This is a really long <Run TextWeight="Bold">hyperlink</Run>. Yeah, a really really long hyperlink, whaddaya think?</Run></Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

You'd get a compile error:

> The object 'Run' already has a child and cannot add ''. 'Run' can accept only one child.

So, as @Scott Whitlock noted, you have to use a `TextBlock` as the inner element and mess around with the `TextDecoration` attributes of the `Hyperlink` and `TextBlock` instead:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <Hyperlink TextDecorations="None"><TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextDecorations="Underline">This is a really long <Run FontWeight="Bold">hyperlink</Run>. Yeah, a really really long hyperlink, whaddaya think?</TextBlock></Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

Sigh. I really hate WPF's `Hyperlink` element. It just doesn't work anything like you'd expect.

Comment: Nice answer! Well summarized!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the style of the Hyperlink to remove the underline.  Then add an underline to the inner TextBlock style itself.

Comment: Care to post some code? I would like to try this but not sure how to remove the underline without breaking the rest of the style. And I'm lazy :-)

Comment: @skypecakes: levanovd's answer is better.  See this for more info: http://www.longhorncorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/TextWPF01062009041311AM/TextWPF.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Scott. That looked promising, but unfortunately won't work for me because I am populating the text with a data binding and on .Net 3.5. You can't bind Run.Text in 3.5. I am less lazy today so I'll see what I can come up with and post the results as an answer to the OP's question, if it's good enough.

Comment: @skypecakes: There are lots of attached property examples out there that you can use to bind non-bindable properties directly in xaml.